# Synchronous (old way) Ext.form.Panel submitting

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I need to submit Ext.form.Panel instance in old way, without any AJAX stuff. I found a few solutions using `standardSubmit: true` parameter. I use it like this:

```
Ext.define('MyForm', {
    id: 'myform',
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    url: '/some/url/'
    standardSubmit: true,
    ...
    buttons: {
        ...
        handler: function () {
            Ext.getCmp('myform').getForm().submit();
        }
    }
})
```

Clicking submit button leads to `No URL specified` error. I tried passing different params combinations in `submit` method but all I get is a lot of weird errors. Could someone share a working example please?

Comment: I found this question while looking for a synchronous Ext.js submit. `standardSubmit` will refresh the entire page.

`Ext.Ajax.request({..., async: false, ...})` was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here what the docs for Ext.form.Panel says

> If subclassing FormPanel, any configuration options for the BasicForm must be applied to the initialConfig property of the FormPanel

So far, the code listed above, should look like this

```
Ext.define('MyForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    ...    
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this
        Ext.apply(me.initialConfig, {
            url: '/some/url',
            standardSubmit: true,
            method: 'GET'
        })
        ...
        me.buttons = {
            ...
            text: 'Submit',
            handler: function () {
                me.getForm().submit();
            }
        }
        me.callParent()
    }
})
```

Definitely not obvious. But it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It works! I've seeked for it for almost one week! The code of Radagast works! No other codes but ext-407-gpl.

```
var login_form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    frame:true,
    title: '<?php echo $this->escape($this->message); ?>',
    url: '<?php echo $this->baseUrl ?>/auth/login',
    standardSubmit: true,
    bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
    width: 350,
    fieldDefaults: {
        msgTarget: 'side',
        labelWidth: 75
    },
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    defaults: {
        anchor: '100%'
    },
items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'login',
        name: 'login_id',
        allowBlank:false
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'password',
        name: 'passwd',
        inputType: 'password'
    }],

    buttons: [{
        text: 'submit',
        type: 'submit',
        handler: function() { this.up('form').getForm().submit(); }
    }, {
        text: 'reset',
        type: 'reset',
        handler: function() { this.up('form').getForm().reset(); }
    }]
});
```